An error occurred when making a type library with IDAClang
When I use IDA's tool IDAClang to make a type library, I always get an error, showing "fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]"。
Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you so much
I saw a prompt in the output log as follows:static assertion failed: error STL1000: Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 17.0.0 or newer.
I don't know how to solve it, this prompt indicates that the built-in clang compiler of 17.0 and above is required.
But I think there should be nothing wrong here, I use IDAclang through Option->complier and there is no problem
